# Why does WPF make working with images so much more difficult?

Tags: wpf, bitmapimage

I used to be able to do so very much with just the `Bitmap` and `Graphics` objects.  Now that I've been using WPF the only thing I seem to be able to do is load an image and show it and make it dance around the stupid screen.  Why did they get rid of these very useful tools.  Are they trying to stupefy .Net?

All I want to do is load an image from a file and cut it into two parts.  This was easy with .Net 2.0 and `System.Drawing`.  But with WPF, I'm hitting a brick wall without using some *very* low level code. I've tried working with `WriteableBitmap`.  But it doesn't seem to really be what I'm wanting. Is there no way to wrap a `DrawingContext` around a `BitmapImage` or something?

Please tell me that WPF is more than HTML for applications. I am REALLY frustrated!!

**Edits:**

Also, how on earth does one save an image *to* a file?

Comment: As for saving images to file (which is a separate question and should be treated as such), try searching for it on the web. Here's one hit: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/10/12/saving-images-bmp-png-etc-in-wpf-silverlight.aspx

Comment: Try using OpenGL. You'll find it's faster and more useful than both GDI+ (System.Drawing) and WPF. OpenTK (www.opentk.com) is a great wrapper for .NET around OpenGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cut the image in two parts, why not use the [`CroppedBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.croppedbitmap.aspx) class?

Consider the following XAML. One source `BitmapImage` shared by two `CroppedBitmaps`, each showing different parts of the source.

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="bmp" UriSource="SomeBitmap.jpg" />
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Image>
        <Image.Source>
            <CroppedBitmap Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=bmp}">
                <CroppedBitmap.SourceRect>
                    <Int32Rect X="0" Y="0" Width="100" Height="100" />
                </CroppedBitmap.SourceRect>
            </CroppedBitmap>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
    <Image>
        <Image.Source>
            <CroppedBitmap Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=bmp}">
                <CroppedBitmap.SourceRect>
                    <Int32Rect X="100" Y="150" Width="50" Height="50" />
                </CroppedBitmap.SourceRect>
            </CroppedBitmap>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</StackPanel>
```

**Update:** to do something similar in code:

```
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(...));
        var sourceRect = new Int32Rect(10, 10, 50, 50);
        var croppedBitmap = new CroppedBitmap(bitmapImage, sourceRect);
```

Comment: Interesting, but I'd want to do this below the XAML, as each piece of image is used in two separate controls.  I'll bet that this is fairly easy to translate into code though. No?

Comment: Absolutely, this is just how you *could* build up the objects in XAML. The same objects (`CroppedBitmap`, `Int32Rect`, etc) can be built in code, no sweat.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is this http://www.nerdparadise.com/tech/csharp/wpfimageediting/

or perhaps you could add a reference to System.Drawing to your project and then do the editing the way you are comfortable with.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that.  Interesting site.  I'm trying really hard not be be that low level.  If I'm going to do things that low level, I'm going to write my own reusable library assembly, and that's a lot of time. Maybe...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably best off using `TransformedBitmap`. Load your Bitmap as a `BitmapSource`, then set the `Transform` property to however you want the image to transform. You have several different transformation options [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transform.aspx). This allows you to rotate, screw, matrix, etc. transformations. If you want to apply more than one, use a `TransformGroup` and apply several transformations at once.

You can also use `BitmapFrame.Create(...)` to work with the transformed image more.

Some Pseudo code:

```
var image = new BitmapSource(...); //Your image
var transformBitmap = new TransformedBitmap(image);
var transformBitmap.Transform = ..//Set your transform;
//optionally:
var frame = BitmapFrame.Create(transformBitmap);
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm wanting the resulting image to be smaller than initial one.

Comment: TransformedBitmap only supports scale transform and rotation transform with angles of multiples of 90 only.